# Moongoose pre init hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a little problem with init hook with Mongoose.
When user gets data, i want to return him a "formatted" value

Here's an example of my code :

```
clientSchema.pre('init', function(next, doc) {
    doc.prop = 'something';
    next(); 
});
```

It works fine, but when I look in db, the property is modified. However, I don't save datas by myself...

How is it possible ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for a **virtuals**, which won't be saved to your database.

Maybe something like this:

```
clientSchema.virtual('formattedProp').get(function() {
  var formatted

  // Use schema properties here to create your formatted value

  return formatted
})
```

You can then access it like so:

```
console.log(client.formattedProp)
```

You can read more here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Note: you might also want to add the following to your schema options:

```
var schema = new Schema(
  {
    // Schema fields
  },
  {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    }
  }
)
```